# Rstudio installation error on Mac

Tags: r, macos, failed-installation

When I installed and opened R studio (0.98.1091) in my Macbook ( OS X 10.9.5), it shows an error message as follows. I have R (3.1.2) in my application, which seems work fine.

I also tried R (3.0.3) which works fine, just in case the higher version of R (3.1.2) conflicts with R studio with some reason. But, each time, R-studio kept giving me the same error message after installed.

```
ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error)
[errormsg=Error in identical(call[[iL]],quote(
doTryCatch)) :
7 arguments passed to .Internal(identical) which
requires 5
, code=local(source("/Volumes/
Rstudio-0.98.1091
1/Rstudio.app/Contents/
Resources/R/ToolsR",local=TRUE, echo=FALSE, verbose=FALSE,
keep.source=FALSE, encoding='UTF-8'))}; OCCURRED
AT:core::Error r::exec::<anaonymous  
namespace>::evaluateExpressionsUnsafe(SEXP,SEXP,SEXP*,sexp::Protect *) /Users
/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/r/RExce.cpp:148
```

It would be much appreciated if anyone could suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Did you install the correct version of R for your current OS? There are two Mac forks at the moment.

Comment: Hi BondedDust, I think so. All "R" versions (3.0.3) (3.1.2 for snowleopard)(3.1.2 for mavericks) were installed separately for testing. All of them worked fine. I downloaded "R" because" RStudio" requires R 2.11.1 (or higher).  As per "RStudio", which I intend to use for taking an online R class, I installed RStudio (0.98.1091)-Mac OS X 10.6+. Since my Mac is 10.9.5, which had been upgraded from Snow Leopard, the "RSudio" should work but it didn't.  I have installed Xquarts, although it would be matter or not.

Comment: So you can start R 3.1.2 in a Terminal session and it works properly? (I would have expected a SL version to produce an error.)

Comment: I didn't use Terminal to open R3.1.2., but I opened R3.1.2 itself and it seems to work. I could open a file from the class using the R3.1.2, so I assume the R3.1.2 works fine. But I didn't do much because I don't have much experience with R.  But for RStudio, when I opened it after installation, it gave an error message right away, which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Also, which directory did you install RStudio in? By the looks of the error message, it looks like it's running off a mounted disk image since the folder Rstudio-0.98.10911 is at the same hierarchy as your base hard drive (i.e. within Volumes).

Comment: What is "R3.1.2 itself"? Are you talking about the R-icon that the Mac-GUI installer creates? Is R in the expected directory? `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/R`

Comment: @JimM @BondedDust( I hope this is a correct way to notify. This is my first time at stackoverflow.) Hi Jim, RStudio was installed automatically in the Application folder, where R has been installed as well. I didn't actively choose the location to install RStudio. After RStudio was downloaded at my Mac, a window popped up showing the Application and RStudio logos.  I dragged the RStudio logo to Application logo, then Rstudio was automatically installed in the Applications folder. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @BondedDust    Hi BondedDust, by "R 3.1.2 itself", I meant double clicking R-icon (looks like circled R) in the Application folder rather than opening R at Terminal (sorry for the confusion. I have limited computer-related vocabulary). When I searched for Application folder in my Mac by search function, R is in the Macintosh HD> Applications folder. (I wish I can do it in a better way, but I can use Terminal barely.) In terminal, R is located ~(my name)$ cd/Applications. It is different from what you wrote for an expected directory, but I think this is a correct directory for R and RStudio.

Comment: @BondedDust  (continued) Previously I had lower versions of R and Rstudio working fine in this Application folder before I upgraded R and RStudio with higher version. I tried to upgrade the versions which the online class recommends to use for the class. By the way, does the second last line of the error message have some clue?:"evaluateExpressionsUnsafe"Thanks for your time,  BondedDust.

Comment: I'd suggest you take this to the RStudio support forum.

Comment: @Roland  Thanks for suggestion, Roland. I have posted my question at the RStudio support forum as well. I am still waiting for a response.